# Getting the value from Firebase and appending it to an array in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sigabrt

I just started learning Swift and I am trying to read the value from every child in the real-time-firebase. I would like to save it as a string in an array. This is what I have tried:

```
           self.ref.child("someId/name").observe(.value) { snapshot in

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let value = snap.value
                self.preis.append(value as! String)
            }
        }
```

But I am always getting the error: **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT** 
in this line: `self.preis.append(value as! String)`

I tried

self.ref.child("someId/name").observe(.value) { snapshot in

```
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let value = snap.value
                self.preis.append(snapshot.value as! String)
            }
        }
```

And now I get the value like this: Optional(...)

Comment: show Firebase structure

Comment: {
  "name" : "Joe"
}

Comment: Did you try to print `value` before the line the app crashes to examine the content?

Comment: I get Optional({
    name = Joe;
})

Comment: Could you try `if let name = value?["name"] as? String {self.preis.append(name)}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
self.ref.child("someId/name").observe(.value) { snapshot in 
   let res = snapshot.value as! String
   print(res)
   self.preis.append(res)
}
```

Comment: try this `print(snapshot.value)` and share log

Comment: Optional(Joe) How do I convert it to just Joe?

Comment: there is no array to loop for it's 1 string item